# Transferring data between MySQL and Oracle databases

Tags: mysql, oracle

Here's the scenario:
I have a MySQL DB, and an Oracle DB, and what I want to do is copy data from MySQL to Oracle, on a scheduled basis.

The process includes just inserting data to a table on the Oracle side, taken from the MySQL db.

Something like this: (oracle command)

```
insert into my_oracle_table  
select * from my_mysql_table@my_mysql_db  
where date > sysdate - 7;
```

What is the best practice for this?  Is there a way to connect say to the MySQL db directly from an Oracle stored procedure? Maybe the other way round?

Oracle 11g and MySql 5.1

Comment: What's the purpose of the transfers?

Comment: back and forth? So both sides can update? Tricky.

Comment: I've edited the original question. Should be less complicated now, I think :)

Answer (score 1):

[Create a database link](http://www.pythian.com/news/1554/how-to-access-mysql-from-oracle-with-odbc-and-sql/) from your Oracle server to the MySQL server.

Once the database link has been established, you can use the standard `insert into.. select from` syntax

```
insert into my_oracle_table  
select * from my_mysql_table@dblinkname
where date > sysdate - 7;
```

---

If you want to do this on a scheduled basis, use [the job scheduler](http://www.oradev.com/dbms_scheduler.jsp) to schedule the transfer.

Comment: The `MERGE` command would probably be better suited for this as it can also update existing rows. But I don't know if that is supported when using a DBLink

Comment: Could you provide the instructions for how to create a database link, as the website you linked to is not gone.

Comment: Looks like this is an updated link to [Create a database link](https://blog.pythian.com/how-to-access-mysql-from-oracle-with-odbc-and-sql/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use O.D.I., Oracle Data Integrator.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/data-integrator/index.html

Oracle Data Integrator is a comprehensive data integration platform that covers all data integration requirements: 
from high-volume, high-performance batch loads, to event-driven, trickle-feed integration processes, to SOA-enabled data services.