# Challenge in getting records present in Oracle but missing in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, oracle

Our client has a system that is integrated to our Company application..the client system connects to Oracle database and our Company application connects to MySQL database.

The client side have given us a view on Oracle that has a set of 4 columns that resemble columns we have on our MySQL database.See below columns in Oracle database and their counterparts/equivalent in MySQL database.

```
Our client [ORACLE]    |    Our Company  [MySQL]

[ORACLE]               |    [MYSQL]

AK_NO                  |    Patient_File_Nr

BIL_NO                 |    Invoice_Nr

PAYMENT_AMT            |    Amount

VOUCHER_DATE           |    Insert_Date
```

I am able to generate records present to each of the databases but then I am not able to figure out a way of getting records missing in either of the databases when doing a comparison check.

How would I write PHP code that connects to both databases and does query for records in MySQL that are not present in Oracle and vice-versa.

Comment: cant u export the data with compatible to mysql??

Comment: Check this question for a (not exactly same but) similar request: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353663/transfering-data-between-mysql-and-oracle-databases

Answer (score 1):

If its a once off.. just export the data from one system into the other ( or into a third system if you don't want to make any alterations to either system), them compare using SQL.

If its a continual process, then probably just a process with php to do it, just open a database handle to each system, do your selects on the tables and compare them programmatically.

Comment: It is a reporting tool...AK_NO in Oracle and Patient_File_Nr both refer to Patient File NO...of which a Patient File NO can have several invoices served to them as BIL_NO in Oracle and Invoice_Nr in MySQL.In both sides an Invoice NO is never repeated [primary_key] in both databases.How would I do this programmatically? I understand I may have to use a user selection from selection GUI page and get Patient File NOs,Invoice NOS,Dates from Oracle result set and loop through the result set of MySQL gotten by using items from Oracle result set in MySQL query...how about an example in code please?