# Is there a way of communiaction between MySQL and Oracle besides ODBC?

Tags: mysql, oracle

So, the question is simple - how to make a query from Oracle to MySQL and the other way around. ODBC is out of the question due to slow performance.

Comment: Have a look at the answers given on this post. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6353663/transfering-data-between-mysql-and-oracle-databases.

It looks like a database link is the answer you may require.

Comment: That link is exactly ODBC.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I am the creator of the MySQL DataController plugin.

As far for Oracle to MSSQL, you may create DBLinks for such queries. There are plenty of documentation on how to create a database link on Oracle using the MSSQL Driver.Just google "Database link from Oracle to SQL Server"

If you want to do the inverse, you may use the plugin that we wrote for mysql. The plugin uses Free-TDS which is an opensource project used to communicate to MSSQL. We have updated a blog about that MySQL Plugin, if you need help compiling it we could help you out.

See the following link  for a short video and blog about the plugin

http://www.acentera.com/mysql-datacontroller/

Answer (score 0):

There is a mysql client library driver for oracle: 
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/DRDAA/mysql_driver.htm

With regards to MySQL you may be able to use the FEDERATED MySQL storage engine

This may also be useful:

"The DataController project is being designed in order to facilitate and provide an easy database integration between MS SQL, Oracle and MySQL databases. It is being designed to provide real-time performant replication between mysql and other databases.. The code is originally derived from MySQL."

https://launchpad.net/datacontroller